# Composed forms of radicals in unicode

Tags: characters

Unicode appears to define the composed forms of some radicals (e.g. 725C 牜or 2EA9 ⺩), but far from all (e.g. the left-half version of 6728 木). Yet there are texts (e.g. figure 18.7 in chapter 18 of the description of the Unicode standard (http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/ch18.pdf) ) which contains that character. Is there a collection of the encodings of the composed radical forms?

Comment: 牜 and ⺩ are not defined by Unicode as *radicals*. Unicode defines radicals in these two documents: http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2F00.pdf and http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2E80.pdf - 牜 and ⺩ are only considered by Unicode as *combining forms*. I don't know why the combining form of 木 is not defined, though.

Comment: @droooze I think the left side form of Tree was not considered different enough to warrant encoding.

Comment: @TomGewecke I thought of that possibility, and found 訁. I don't think 訁 warrants a separate encoding from 言 if it's a similarity issue.

Comment: @droooze Yes, you're right.  Hard to know sometimes why some han characters got  included and some not.  Compatibility with legacy encodings and even plain mistakes can be factors.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but again, in the reference above (figure 18.7 of Chapter 18 in http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/ch18.pdf) the left-side form of tree does appear. So is it a picture drawing there and not an encoded character?